# When to convert a categorical variable into a numerical variable for machine learning?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, xgboost

I am new to machine learning and I am running a classification algorithm (`xgboost`) on my data, using the `caret` package in `R`.

However, I am confused regarding the conversion of some categorical variables into numerical variables for the purpose of machine learning. I have scoured the web but I cannot find a specific rule, if it exists, on the subject.

The `xgboost` vignette at the following url ([xgboost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/discoverYourData.html#introduction)) mentions that "Xgboost manages only numeric vectors." Doesn't that mean that all my features (variables) need to contain only numeric values? However, I've seen some tutorials using `xgboost` where the variables were categorical variables.

Any help on the subject would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Might I recommend a [primer on one-hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f)?

Comment: *"xgboost manages only numeric vectors." Doesn't that mean that all my features (variables) need to contain only numeric values?* Short answer: **yes**.

Comment: @blacksite Thanks for that link! Interesting read.

Comment: Longer answer: pretty much any model only runs on numbers (from linear models to gradient boosted trees). R packages often auto-convert the categorical variables to numerics in an appropriate way before calling the model routine, especially when you use a `formula` interface. However, `xgboost` doesn't have a formula method, so you're on your own.

Comment: @blacksite If I understand that article correctly, for each categorical variable in my data set, I will need to convert all of its levels into features? That is, if say, column Market has 3 levels, I will need to have 3 new columns, and so on for the rest of those columns which are categorical.

Comment: You don't have to do it manually. I'd look at R's ```model.matrix``` and ```sparse.model.matrix``` which will do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary way categorical features are treated in statistics/machine learning is through a mechanism called [one-hot encoding](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/321/lec/W04/onehot.pdf).

Take the following data, for example:

```
outcome    animal
      1       cat
      1       dog
      0       dog
      1       cat
```

Say you wanted to predict outcome (whatever that is) based on the type of animal a given case (observation/row/subject/etc.). The way to do this is to encode `animal` in a one-hot fashion, like this:

```
outcome  is_dog   is_cat
      1       0        1
      1       1        0
      0       1        0
      1       0        1
```

Where the animal column of cardinality *k* has been encoded into *k* new columns indicating the presence or absence of a particular category/attribute given the value for `animal` for that row.

From there, you can use whatever model you want to predict outcome based off of (the now differently-encoded) animal column. But make sure to leave one animal (one group) out of the model as the control group. In this case, you might fit a logistic regression model `outcome ~ is_dog` and interpret the slope coefficient for `is_dog` as the increase or decrease in likelihood of the 1 outcome for a dog **in comparison to a cat**.